# Rank/Running Totals of data set in PowerBI

Tags: powerbi, dax

I'm trying to get a running total of sales from my data set to build a build cumulative percentage column but am having some issues doing so.  I have tried the following

This just returns 1's.  TotalSales is a measure I created from multiplying qtysold*price from the productsales table.

```
RANK = 

var a = RANKX(ProductSales,[TotalSales])

RETURN
a
```

This one appears to count the lines

```
RANK3 = 

RANKX(
ProductSales, sum(ProductSales[ExtPrice])
)
```

My data is by part number, Total Sales with year and quarter slicers.  I'd like to rank the parts in descending order from highest to lowest and eventually divide that number by overall total sales to get an 80/20 percentage.

Here is a screen shot of what I would like to end up with.  I think I can get the 80/20 percent if I can get the running total working.

```
Part Number     Sales       Rank     RunningTotal
031-01520       639283.51   1        639,283.51
UP-LF4575050    476064.00   2        1,115,347.51
51301           420394.52   3        1,535,742.03
```

Thanks for any help!!

Comment: so you want the ranking to happen by running total?

Comment: I was wanting to rank by the sales column descending. Everything I've read online says I need to use the rink column then to do the running total.

Comment: You want to rank by the sales column? Why do you need running total ?

Comment: I will take the running total and divide it by the overall sales to get the cumulative percentage for the 80/20 data. Everywhere I have read says I need to use rank to get the correct running total. Do you know a way to get the running total of the sales column without using rank?

Comment: check my you tube video here https://youtu.be/svkV9dbvjzY
This calculates running totals without using rank